# Java Code Reading

Tags: java

```
int a = 4;
if( 1 == 0 ) {
   a = 2;
   if(0 != 1) {
      a = 2;
   }
   else {
      a = 11;
   }
}
else {
   a /= 15;
}
```

I am trying to figure out the value of "a" in this code. The answer key states that the value is 0, but when I read it I get 2 as the value of a.

I get 2 because of this line (if 0!= 2){ a = 2;
Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you were to indent your code properly, then the answer should be clearer.

Comment: a /= 15; ?? this must give some error!!

Comment: It won't give any error - `a /= 15 == 0` as `a == 4` and is an int.  Most of the code is redundant because it's in a block which will never be entered because `1 == 0` is never true.

Comment: ya right..that is division..just got it

Comment: Can't you just run it and see what you get?  Why would you ask the Stack Overflow community to run your program for you?

Comment: @DavidWallace I suspect it was asked because running the program will tell you what the answer is, but not why it is.

Comment: @Alan Ah, of course.  All is clear.  Quicker to use Stack Overflow than to read the docs on how to use a debugger.

Comment: `a /= 15` is the same as `a = 4 / 15`.  because `a` is an int, any value less than a whole number becomes truncated; in this case, a value less than 1 becomes 0.  In other words, truncating to an int drops off everything after the decimal point. 4 / 15 = '0.26666666666', and truncates to `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get:

```
a = 4 / 15;
```

Which is `0`.

You have to notice that `(0 == 1)` is `false`...

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( 1 == 0 ) {
    a = 2;
    if ( 0 != 1 ) {
       a = 2;
    } else {
       a = 11;
    } // this is all dead code since 1 !=0
} else {
    a /= 15;  // this will execute 
}
```

4/15 = 0 as a is integer.